# Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 5.21.1 ToView() causes table creation

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Since an upgrade to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 5.21.1 running an "Add-Migration" command produces a migration which creates a table for the entity that is mapped to a view.
The view was created before the upgrade of the library and different migration was generated before the upgrade as well, and there was no table creation, so I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the upgrade of the package itself.

My question is am I doing something wrong here, or did I miss something in the new EF Core release. Or is it simply a bug

The entity in question is a simple POCO

```
public class SimpleClass
{
   public string PropertyOne { get; set;}
   public long PropertyTwo { get; set; }
   public long PropertyThree { get; set; }
}
```

And the context itself looks like this

```
public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<ContextOptions> options):base(options) {}
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleClass>( sc => 
        {
            sc.HasNoKey();
            sc.ToView("VIEWNAME", "Schema");
        }
    }
    
    public virtual DbSet<SimpleClass> SimpleClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Running the Add-Migration command produces the following migration

```
public partial class migration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "SimpleClasses",
            columns: table => new 
            {
                PropertyOne = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: true),
                PropertyTwo = table.Column<long>(type: "NUMBER(19)", nullable: false),
                PropertyThree = table.Column<long>(type: "NUMBER(19)", nullable: false),
            },
            constraints: table => 
            {
            });
    }
    
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "SimpleClasses");
    }
}
```

And this designer code

```
[DbContext(typeof(DatabaseContext))]
[Migration("migration")]
partial class migration
{
    protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity("Domain.Models.PriorityTask", b =>
        {
            b.Property<string>("PropertyOne")
                .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2(2000)")
                .HasColumnName("PropertyOne");

            b.Property<long>("PropertyTwo")
                .HasColumnType("NUMBER(19)")
                .HasColumnName("PropertyTwo");

            b.Property<long>("PropertyThree")
                .HasColumnType("NUMBER(19)")
                .HasColumnName("PropertyThree");

            b.ToTable("SimpleClasses");

            b.ToView("ViewName", "Schema");
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually a breaking change for the new version of EF Core 5.0, which I apparently looked over.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#toview